# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND While Creating Docusaurus Files

Tags: documentation, docusaurus

I am using Docusaurus to create documentation.
To create static files using below command.

```
 npm run build
```

But there is a problem in build directory. It is adding source as following:

```
<script src="/styles.1c10c9f3.js"></script>

<script src="/runtime~main.936f7875.js"></script>

<script src="/main.5d1426ac.js"></script>

<script src="/common.46a79f08.js"></script>

<script src="/ece76bd1.9a3d5346.js"></script>
```

So it cause problem while loading it:

```
GET file:///C:/styles.2039b83b.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2index.html:22 GET file:///C:/img/logo.svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:25 GET file:///C:/styles.1c10c9f3.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:27 GET file:///C:/runtime~main.936f7875.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:29 GET file:///C:/main.5d1426ac.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:31 GET file:///C:/common.46a79f08.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:33 GET file:///C:/2.d1c81d83.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:35 GET file:///C:/1be78505.8a34320a.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:37 GET file:///C:/20ac7829.5dd9332a.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:39 GET file:///C:/17896441.f0de57b0.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:41 GET file:///C:/7366bc9d.edc04dbd.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```